# sed: subsitute in line that contains X but does not contain Y

Tags: sed

I am looking for an elegant solution that combines both of these commands:

```
sed -i '/Y/! s/replace/with/' /path/to/file
sed -i '/X/ s/replace/with/' /path/to/file
```

I tried

```
sed -i '/X/ /Y/! s/replace/with/' /path/to/file
```

which does not work. Is there an elegant solution for that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like `sed '/X/ {/Y/! s/replace/with/}'` maybe?

```
$ sed '/X/ {/Y/! s/replace/with/}' << EOF
X replace X
X replace Y
Y replace X
Y replace Y
EOF
X with X
X replace Y
Y replace X
Y replace Y
```

Comment: Works only with GNU sed. On Solaris you will get: `Unrecognized command: /X/ {/Y/! s/replace/with/}`